# Getting Tab Title in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Preface, I am an extreme novice here.

I am making an extension to record the URL and Tab Title of visited websites. The code I have below is giving me everything except the Tab Title, I get "undefined". I am unsure how to go about getting the tab title:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
function(info) {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=FORMKEY", true);
var params = "entry.0.single=" + info.url + "&entry.1.single=" + info.tabid; 
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send(params);
} ,{ urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]}
);
```

The output I see is:

```
4/1/2013 12:53:35   http://www.url.com/ undefined
```

Anyone give me a point as to what I am doing incorrectly on getting the tab title?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your code that you would be getting the title. `info` doesn't contain that data but instead contains the `tabId` which you misspelled (source of the undefined). You can use that `info.tabId` to get the tab and use that tab object to get the title like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(info) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=FORMKEY";
  req.open("POST", url, true);
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId,function(tab){
    var params = "entry.0.single=" + info.url + "&entry.1.single=" + tab.title; 
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(params);
  });
},
{ urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]});
```